# Intersection Observer: When element is in view stat counter goes up as should but once out of view and back it view - stat counter doesn't stop

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry for another question but this is my first time using intersection observer and it's working partially. Once the elements are intersecting for the first time the stat counter rises as it should but once they are not intersecting and go back to intersecting the counter goes well beyond the value and doesn't stop. How can I prevent that from happening?

```js
let statContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("stat-container");

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(stat => {
    stat.forEach(stat => {
        if (stat.isIntersecting) {
            for (var i = 0; i < statContainer.length; i++) {
                let container = statContainer[i];
              
                let circularProgress = container.querySelector(".circular-progress"),
                    progressValue = container.querySelector(".progress-value");
              
                let progressStartValue = 0,
                    progressEndValue = progressValue.textContent,
                    speed = 10;
              
                let progress = setInterval(() => {
                  progressStartValue++;
              
                  progressValue.textContent = `${progressStartValue}%`;
                  circularProgress.style.background = `conic-gradient(#099bf0, #7cbf3d,#00b3cf, #1f58f2, #5618d4 ${progressStartValue * 3.6}deg, #EAEAEC 0deg)`;
              
                  if (progressStartValue == progressEndValue) {
                    clearInterval(progress);
                  }
                }, speed);
              }
        } else {
            console.log("not intersecting")
        }
    })
    
});

observer.observe(statContainer[0]);
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #7d2ae8;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    width: 420px;
    padding: 50px 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #fff;
    row-gap: 30px;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.circular-progress{
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: conic-gradient(#7d2ae8 3.6deg, #ededed 0deg);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.circular-progress::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 210px;
    width: 210px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.progress-value{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #7d2ae8;
}
.text{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #606060;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="spacer"></div>

    <div class="stat-container">
        <div class="circular-progress">
            <span class="progress-value">
                55
            </span>
        </div>
        
        <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="stat-container">
        <div class="circular-progress">
            <span class="progress-value">
                70
            </span>
        </div>
        
        <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="stat-container">
        <div class="circular-progress">
            <span class="progress-value">
                67
            </span>
        </div>
        
        <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you edit the textContent of the div directly. And on the second time this produces an invalid number, so it will never stop. (because on the second run you add a `%` to the text... and `50%` will never be `50`.

I propose to store the value in a data attribute, then this value will never change and always be evaluated to the correct end value.

If you need to never play the animation again after it reaches max value and you need to unsubscribe from the observer.

```js
let statContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("stat-container");

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(stat => {
    stat.forEach(stat => {
        if (stat.isIntersecting) {
            for (var i = 0; i < statContainer.length; i++) {
                let container = statContainer[i];
              
                let circularProgress = container.querySelector(".circular-progress"),
                    progressValue = container.querySelector(".progress-value");
              
                let progressStartValue = 0,
                    progressEndValue = progressValue.dataset.max,
                    speed = 10;
              
                let progress = setInterval(() => {
                  progressStartValue++;
              
                  progressValue.textContent = `${progressStartValue}%`;
                  circularProgress.style.background = `conic-gradient(#099bf0, #7cbf3d,#00b3cf, #1f58f2, #5618d4 ${progressStartValue * 3.6}deg, #EAEAEC 0deg)`;
              
                  if (progressStartValue == progressEndValue) {
                    clearInterval(progress);
                  }
                }, speed);
              }
        } else {
            console.log("not intersecting")
        }
    })
    
});

observer.observe(statContainer[0]);
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #7d2ae8;
    height: 500hv;
}
.container{
    display: flex;
    width: 420px;
    padding: 50px 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #fff;
    row-gap: 30px;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.circular-progress{
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: conic-gradient(#7d2ae8 3.6deg, #ededed 0deg);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.circular-progress::before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 210px;
    width: 210px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.progress-value{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #7d2ae8;
}
.text{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #606060;
}
```

```html
<div class="stat-container">
        <div class="circular-progress">
            <span class="progress-value" data-max="55">
                55
            </span>
        </div>
        
        <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="stat-container">
        <div class="circular-progress">
            <span class="progress-value" data-max="70">
                70
            </span>
        </div>
        
        <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="stat-container">
        <div class="circular-progress">
            <span class="progress-value" data-max="67">
                67
            </span>
        </div>
        
        <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
    </div>
<div style="min-height: 500vh"> </div>
```

Comment: How would I be able to take the value of the span and insert it into the data-max attr without having to type it twice? This will be turned into a module where the user would enter the value once.

Comment: This is for you to figure out. Maybe you require the user to add this attribute so it is useable? You could also do a check if there is a data-attribute set on load before you initialize the observer. If it is not set, you use the value inside the span and set the data-attribute. Then you use the data-attribute as value.
Edit: also what happens if they write XXX as value? then it also will never work and spin endlessly. You will have to come up with some sort of error handling and make it robust